# Accessing singular points in multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

The code below would work great in getting every other item in a regular array.

```
letters = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j"]]
letters.each.with_index do |i, index|
  if (index %2 ==0)  then
    puts "#{[index, i]}"
  end
end
```

But in multidimensional, I can't figure how to get the second item of each array from `0` -> `b`, `1` -> `d` etc. Any ideas?

Comment: By any chance, is `letters.flatten.each.with_index` what you want?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]".

Comment: hey tin man, thanks.. to me this was the simplest way of writing the code. Not everyone is an expert yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
letters.each do |letter|
  puts letter[1] # Will give you second item of sub array
end
```

If you want to get the items at even indexes of the sub array, you have to loop through the sub array also

```
letters.each do |letter|
  letter.each.with_index do |l, i|
    if (i %2 ==0)  then
      puts "#{[l, i]}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, i used your second example to get the second item of each sub array by changing the condition of i %2 ==0 (1st item ) to i %2 == 1 (2nd item). Thanks for writing out this way, it helps me understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget about the simple :first and :last properties of arrays.

```
irb(main):001:0> letters = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j"]]
=> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j"]]
irb(main):002:0>  puts letters.map(&:last).to_s
["b", "d", "f", "h", "j"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters.each_index.zip(letters.transpose.last)
  #=> [[0, "b"], [1, "d"], [2, "f"], [3, "h"], [4, "j"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following :

```
letters = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j"]]
letters.each.with_index do |element, index|
    if (index %2 ==0)  then
        puts "#{[index, element[1]]}"
    end
end

=> [0, "b"]
   [2, "f"]
   [4, "j"]
```

While you iterate over `letters`, `element` is an array. You can access its fields as is.

EDIT:
If you really want all the elements just remove the condition:

```
letters = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j"]]
letters.each.with_index do |element, index|
    puts "#{[index, element[1]]}"
end

=> [0, "b"]
   [1, "d"]
   [2, "f"]
   [3, "h"]
   [4, "j"]
```

Comment: please read the question carefully, your solution does not prints `"d"` and `"h"` but the requirement is **how to get the second item of each array from 0 -> b, 1 -> d etc.**

Comment: Well I think the OP at least knows what the condition inside the loop is about. The question is probably wrong. Anyway I will edit my answer to cover both interpretations of the question.